# How to answer the question "have you got something" (meaning: do you have something)

Tags: expressions

> Have you got a brother? (meaning: Do you have a brother?)

How do you answer this question?

> Yes, I do.

or

> Yes, I have.

or either?

Comment: In AmE, I've seen instances of "Yes, I have" meaning "Yes, I do"

Comment: Do you mean you haven't seen instances of "Yes, I do"? It's very unusual?

Comment: No, the response "Yes, I do" is the most common one, but I have seen "Yes, I have" used in AmE as well (but we'd better wait for a confirmation from our American friends)

Comment: Do you speak British English? Can you tell me how British people respond, please? Do they use "Yes, I do" as the most common way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have you got a brother?

Yes, I have.

> Do you have a brother?

Yes, I do.

Comment: I am a native speaker of American English.  This response is what is technically correct.  However, I think I wouldn't bat an eye if someone responded "Yes, I do," to "Have you got a brother" since I would think of it as a short version of "Yes, I do have one."  In that case, the precise idioms used in the question and answer wouldn't match, but I don't think I would notice.